# SKNode! is not convertible to "SKNode"

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I got this problem and can't resolve it, I don't really understand the documentation on unwrapping variables

```
var ladybug: SKNode = SKNode.childNodeWithName("ladybug")
```

Error:  (String!) -> SKNode! is not convertible to "SKNode"

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method works fine:

```
var sprite = SKNode()
var ladybug: SKNode! = sprite.childNodeWithName("ladybug")
```

But you need to call the method on an instance of SKNode, not SKNode itself.

Comment: that was just an example to show you have to use an instance ok SKNode. As rickster said, if you're inside an SKScene class you can try `self.childNodeWithName("ladybug")`

Comment: This answer uses an **empty** SKNode that's been created just for illustration. If you have an **actual** SKNode initialized AND that node **has** a child node with name "ladybug", it should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

`childNodeWithName` isn't a class method. You call it on an instance, not the `SKNode` class itself.

If you're writing this code inside an `SKScene` subclass, the instance you want to call this method on might be `self`.

Answer (score 1):

childNodeWithName returns an optional SKNode!. Use the type inference and remember, you must retrieve the node from its parent (usually self, the SKScene)

```
let ladybug = self.childNodeWithName("ladybug")
```

And this is what it's like when you create the sprite

```
let ladybug = SKSpriteNode(ImageNamed:"ladybug.png")
labybug.name = "ladybug"
self.addChild(ladybug)
```

Try to use let instead of var for objects. You can modify its properties without problem but it's better to use constants.